# How to pass command line options to the java compiler through the <javac> Ant task using <compilerarg value="">?

Tags: ant, javac

To compile code using preview features, `javac` requires options `--enable-preview` and `--release`.

If I pass these options to the `<javac>` Ant task (Ant 1.10.5) using the `line` attribute, as shown below, compilation succeeds.

```
<compilerarg line="--enable-preview --release 15"/>
```

But if I pass them as individual arguments using the `value` attribute, as shown below, Ant throws `error: invalid flag: --release 15`.

```
<compilerarg value="--enable-preview"/>
<compilerarg value="--release 15"/>
```

Since the Ant manual [says](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) "It is highly recommended to avoid the line version when possible", I'd like to know how to make the code work with the `value` attribute as well.  What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be three arguments, like:

```
<compilerarg value="--enable-preview"/>
<compilerarg value="--release"/>
<compilerarg value="15"/>
```

... otherwise, as you saw, "--release 15" is treated as a single argument with an embedded space.

Comment: Of all the combinations I tried, I had to miss that one...  Thx!